# CSV file can accept more than 650 rows

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am trying to write data in CSV file. In the previous version of my application, I need to write more about 1500 rows, but the program was writing only 1300 (And half of line 1301). Now I am trying to type in CSV file about 700 rows, and the program is typing only 650 (and half of line 651).

Using Spring WebFlux,
and lib OpenCSV

Comment: `And half of line 1301`, that sounds the output stream is not closed or flushed correctly. But without any code, impossible to say. Post your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that I  have forgotten to add  flush method in some method.